# Simple prover9 test not working

Tags: logic, theorem-proving, first-order-logic

I have a file that i am using as input for the theorem prover prover9. It only contains assumptions. I decided to test prover9 by using one of the assumptions as the goal. Obviously this should be proven.

However, i get the warning 'denials share constants' and then 'search failed'. The file is shown below

```
formulas(assumptions).

% this is the given data -------------------------------------------

parent(adam, jill).    parent(eve, jill).    parent(adam, bill).    parent(eve, bill).
parent(ed, mary).      parent(ann, mary).    parent(ed, diana).     parent(ann, diana).
parent(bill, cathy).   parent(mary, cathy).  parent(bill, jon).     parent(mary, jon).
parent(phil, sue).     parent(sheila, sue).  parent(phil, ben).     parent(sheila, ben).
parent(jim,beth).      parent(cathy, beth).  parent(jim, tony).     parent(cathy, tony).
parent(jon, pat).      parent(sue, pat).     parent(dave, ruth).    parent(liz, ruth).
parent(dave, vicky).   parent(liz, vicky).   parent(tony, ron).     parent(ruth, ron).
parent(pat, harry).    parent(ben, henry).   parent(henry, helen).

male(adam). male(bill).  male(ed).    male(jon).   male(phil).  male(ben).  male(pat).
male(jim).  male(tony).  male(harry). male(henry). male(dave).  male(ron).  male(sam).

female(eve).   female(ann).    female(jill).   female(mary). female(vicky). female(helen).
female(diana). female(sheila). female(cathy).  female(sue).  female(beth).   female(ruth).
female(liz).   female(pat).

married(adam, eve).  married(ed, ann).  married(jill, sam).  married(bill, mary).
married(phil, sheila). married(dave, liz). married(cathy, jim). married(jon, sue).
married(tony, ruth).

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% This is the given grandparent definition

all X all Y ( grandparent(X,Y) <-> (exists Z (parent(X,Z) & parent(Z,Y))) ).

% -------------------------------------------------------------------
% this is the additional data for testing sister property

adam != eve.      jill != bill.      ed != ann.      mary != diana.
sue  != ben.      mary != bill.     jon != cathy.   cathy != jim.
dave != liz.     vicky != ruth.    phil != sheila.   tony != beth.

% --------------------------------------------------------------------


end_of_list.

set(prolog_style_variables).



formulas(goals).

parent(adam, jill).

end_of_list.
```